# How to change the position of a display object from one point to another?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

a display object container on the stage has some bitmap images of sizes 50x50 arranged in a order one by one. Now if i click on any of the thumbnail image (bitmap) the entire container should move and position itself so that, the bitmap image clicked is placed in the center of the stage.

How can we do this in ActionScript 3.0. Can somebody point out an example or a resource please?

Comment: just change its coordinates??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
thumbnail.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _position);

function _position(e:Event):void
{
    var thumb:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target);

    container.x = -thumb.x + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
    container.y = -thumb.y + (stage.stageHeight / 2);
}
```

Comment: You beat me too it.. But I would note, that you are assuming `container` is not within another container that has been moved.

Comment: @Sravan0313 But isn't that kind of what this solution does? It moves the entire container, and it calculates where to move it by subtracting the thumb's position *relative to the container*. The whole thing works, *because* "the bitmap's coordinates inside the container are different".

Comment: @Sravan0313 Your solution is far more complicated than necessary... but suit yourself.

Comment: @Sravan0313 I understand the problem, and so did Marty Wallace.  You're just making it more complex than necessary.

Comment: @MartyWallace and weltraumpirat thanks alot for the help. appreciate the help alot